# Ruby Mongo Driver: How To Look For Date Intervals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongodb-ruby

Given a init date and today, what's the query to search for all "names" between that date?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**MongoMapper**

You should be able to use MongoMapper's query operators. Suppose your have a "User" model with a "created_on" date, you could use this to get the names. (I believe MongoDB uses UTC Times to store all date/time objects):

```
initial_date = Time.utc(2011, 5, 1) # 2011-05-01 00:00:00 UTC
@users = User.where(:created_on => {:$gte => initial_date, :$lte => Time.now.utc})
@users.each do |user|
  puts user.name
end
```

**Ruby Mongo Driver**

```
initial_date = Time.utc(2011, 5, 1) # 2011-05-01 00:00:00 UTC
@conn = Mongo::Connection.new
@db = @conn['my_db']
@collection = @db['users']
@users = @collection.find(:created_on => {:$gte => initial_date, :$lte => Time.now.utc})
@users.each do |user|
  puts user['name']
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't use "where". I'm using the ruby mongo driver not mapper. sorry. thanks

Comment: The "initial_date" must be in which format? I can't make it match anything.

Comment: @donald: That query format actually works with both drivers. See my updated answer. Initial date needs to be a UTC Time.